# newUser coming up undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication

I am fairly new to Express and am trying to create a simple authentication login/register form. "newUser" is coming up undefined and I am not really sure why.... any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
```

---

```
let express = require("express");
let router = express.Router();
let mongojs = require("mongojs");
let db = mongojs("carapp", ["users"]);
let bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
let passport = require("passport");
let LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

// login GET PAGE
router.get("/login", function(req, res) {
res.render("login");
});

// Register GET PAGE
router.get("/register", function(req, res) {
  res.render("register");
});
// Register POST
router.post("/register", function(req, res) {
  let name = req.body.name;
  let email = req.body.email;
  let username = req.body.username;
  let password = req.body.password;
  let confirm_password = req.body.confirm_password;

  // Validation
  req.checkBody("name", "Name field is required").notEmpty();
  req.checkBody("email", "Email field is required").notEmpty();
  req.checkBody("email", "Please use a Valid Email Address").isEmail();
  req.checkBody("username", "Username field is required").notEmpty();
  req.checkBody("password", "Password field is required").notEmpty();
  req.checkBody("confirm_password", "Passwords Do Not 
  Match".equals(req.body.password);

  // Check For Errors

  let errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    console.log("Form has errors");
    res.render("register", {
      errors: errors,
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password,
      confirm_password: confirm_password
    });
  } else {
    let newUser = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password
    };
  }

  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      newUser.password = hash;

  db.users.insert(newUser, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      console.log("User Added. Good JOB using MONGODB Matt!");
      req.flash("success", "You are registered and can log in");
      res.location("/");
      res.redirect("/");
    }
  });
});
});

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user._id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    db.users.findOne({ _id: mongojs.OnjectId(id) }, function(err, user{
   done(err, user);
    });
  });

  passport.use(
new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
  db.users.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect Username" });
    }

    bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect Password" });
      }
    });
  });
})
);

  // Login Post
  router.post("/login",passport.authenticate("local",{
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/users/login",
    failureFlash: "Invalid Username or Password"
  } +
    function(req, res) {
      console.log("Auth Successful");
      res.redirect("/");
        }
    )
  );
});
module.exports = router; //brackets needed here
```

---

Here is my package.json file

```
 {
  "name": "cars",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "car buying application",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
   "start" : "nodemon"
  },
 "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
  "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
  "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
  "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
  "ejs": "^2.6.1",
  "express": "^4.16.4",
  "express-messages": "^1.0.1",
  "express-session": "^1.15.6",
   "mongojs": "^2.6.0",
   "passport": "^0.4.0",
   "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
   "pug": "^2.0.3"
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`let` [only exists in its block scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Description).

When you declare it in a `{}` block but close the block immediately, it is effectively a no-op.

In your original code:

```
  // newUser = undefined
  } else {
    let newUser = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password
    };
    // newUser = Object
  }
  // newUser = undefined
```

You can try something like:

```
 let newUser;
 // newUser = undefined
 ....
  } else {
    newUser = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      username: username,
      password: password
    };
    // newUser = Object
  }
  // newUser = Object
```

Comment: it was your original code, you should rewrite it using `var` or put `let newUser` outside the block. Added a simple edited version

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed body-parser. You body may not be in JSON format.

Comment: thanks for the reply! i do have body-parser installed- Version "1.18.3"